# .NET Regex - Get string after match

Tags: .net, regex

I am working with some strings that are usually following the next format:

> word1 word2 word3 word4

My initial goal was to return the string's part coming after the second space and so to get:

> word3 word4

I searched a bit how to do so and I only succeed to retrieve the first two words including the second space ("word1 word2 ") thanks to the next regex:

```
^([^\s]*\s[^\s]*)\s
```

Now to match my initial goal, I would like to find way to return the rest of the string that actually didn't match the given patter. Any idea ?

It's important to notify that I also have to handle the next cases:

```
"" -> ""
"word1" -> ""
"word1 word2" -> ""
"word1 word2 word3" -> "word3"
"word1 word2 word3 word4 wordX" -> "word3 word4 wordX"
```

Basically to return everything after the second spacing (if there is any obviously !). I also would like to avoid the Replace or any other methods.

I thank you all in advance for your response and wish you a great day !
Best regards,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may rely on a variable length lookbehind in .NET regex:

```
(?<=^(?:\S+\s+){2}).+
```

See the [.NET regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%28%3F%3C%3D%5E%28%3F%3A%5CS%2B%20%2B%29%7B2%7D%29.%2B&i=%0D%0Aword1%0D%0Aword1%20word2%0D%0Aword1%20word2%20word3%0D%0Aword1%20word2%20word3%20word4%20wordX&o=m) (`\s` replaced with a space since that is a multiline string demo, you may replace the space with `[\s-[\r\n]]` or `[\p{Zs}\t]` to only match horizontal whitespace chars).

**Details**

- `(?<=^(?:\S+\s+){2})` - the positive lookbehind that will match a location that is immediately preceded with 2 occurrences of 1+ non-whitespace chars followed with 1+ whitespace chars at the start of the string
- `.+` - 1+ chars other than a newline (if `(?s)` is added at the pattern start, `.` with match any chars).

Comment: It's working like a charm ! Thank you for everything Wiktor !! :)

Comment: Done ! I couldn't do so before since I only earned the upvoting privilege last night. Again, thank you for everything !!

Answer (score 1):

No need for Regex. You can try this:

```
var inputString = "word1 word2 word3 word4";
string.Join(" ", inputString.Split(' ').ToList().Skip(2).ToList());
```

Comment: My original message was maybe not very clear, but Wiktor is correct. I wanted to reach my goal without using some C# code. Anyway thank you for your response Kots !

Answer (score 1):

This one also matches

```
^(?:(\w+ ?)?(\w+ ?)?)(.*$)
```

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/vK5YBl/1)

Comment: Hi ! My regex tester (regexstorm) is not returning the same matches as yours. Maybe the results may change depending on the flavors ?

Comment: did you check it at `regex101.com` ?

Comment: I did check your demo. ;) I simply noticed different results depending on the used website and was wondering where they may come come from. In any case, thank you for your response !